# Existence of a $P \in D$ such that $f(P) \int_D g = g(P) \int_D f.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, compactness, connectedness

Let $D \subset \Bbb R^n$ be compact and connected.

Suppose $f,g : D \to \Bbb R$ are a pair of positive definite continuous functions. Then there exists a $P \in D$ such that $$f(P) \int_D g = g(P) \int_D f.$$

I think we have to use some version of Mean Value Theorem here but unable to proceed with the problem.

Require some Hints to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try integrating the function $x\mapsto f(x)\int_Dg(y)\, dy - g(x)\int_Df(y)\, dy$ over $D$. Then you can use a variant of the mean value theorem for integrals, which can be stated like this:

Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be connected and compact, $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then there exists a $\xi\in D$ such that
$$\int_D f\, dx=f(\xi)\lambda(D).$$
Here $\lambda$ denotes the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue Measure.

Hint for this statement: $f$ attains its minimal and maximal values and every value inbetween since $D$ is connected.

One thing is puzzeling me though. My argument does not need $f,g\geq 0$...